# [Bug]: error RSA PRIVATE KEY not found from while creating test certificate

Tags: openssl, x509certificate, device, azure-iot-hub, provisioning

Following this code repo :-- https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node

and working on the certificate generate file --- https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/main/provisioning/tools/create_test_cert.js

Done All the required process  for the project setup (ex-NPM install , Open SLL install   and other required steps)

But when I try to create the root certificate for provisioning x509 device (ie---create_test_cert.js root "Test Root Certificate") , I'm getting this error in the  beginning it self so not able to execute other steps

Can you please suggest any way to resolve this issue ,I will be very grateful.

Could not create certificate: RSA PRIVATE KEY not found from open SSL output:

Comment: I have utilized the code and could create the certificate without issues. Are you sure your OpenSSL is configured correctly? I have used the following resource to [setup OpenSSL on windows machine](https://thesecmaster.com/procedure-to-install-openssl-on-the-windows-platform/)

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is with the Open SSL configuration and not the code. I have tested the code on windows machine with Open SSL version 1.1.1i and could generate the certificates without any issues. Please refer the below image to find the list of certificates I managed to generate using the create_test_certificate.js file.

[image]

If you are testing the code on a windows machine, make sure that OpenSSL_CONF is set to the path of your openssl.cfg file and the path environment variable is set to you bin directory of Open SSL. Refer the following images for additional details

[image]

[image]

If you are testing the code on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server and Open SSL version 3.x.x, there is an open bug reported on [github](https://github.com/coder/code-server/issues/5162) around this error. There is a work around provided on the thread to make use of [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert) to generate the keys.

If the above approaches do not work for you, there is also another SDK shared on [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/tree/main/tools/CACertificates) through which you can generate CA certificates. Follow the steps outlined in the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-x509-scripts) to generate test certificates using the scripts in the repository.